# LogCat window not able to get on eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

A few days back I installed Eclipse with ADT, but now am not able get LogCat
window, I tried so many times but no result, how to get logcat back on eclipse.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the DDMS perspective?

Have you tried Window > View 
search for "Android" or "LogCat"

Comment: Remember to have your emulator selected in DDMS view as well, or it won't populate the logcat.

Comment: Thanks Dave G,  Actually on left hand side of eclipse show view as fast Icon is there i clicked on that and got LogCat